# css how to prevent content from drifting underneath fixed position areas?

Tags: css, html

I've created an HTML template where I have a sidebar set to `position: fixed;` but when I minimize the browser to less width than the page is set to, the main content drifts underneath the sidebar when the user viewing sidescrolls.

Is there any fix to set the entire container with sidebar and the main content to be like a single fixed block?

http://jsfiddle.net/vuj6t/2/

```
<body>
<div id="container">

<section id="sidebar">
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="/"></a></li>
<li><a href="/"></a></li>
<li><a href="/"></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</section>

<section id="stream">

<article>
</article>

<article>
</article>

<article>
</article>

</section>

</div>
</body>


body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
}

#sidebar {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
}

#stream {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 0 210px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 490px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just *absolutely* position the sidebar on narrow screens using a simple media query like

```
@media (max-width: 690px) {
  #sidebar { position:absolute; }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vuj6t/3/